# AWS ECR image is taking too much time to run

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm new to AWS ECS service. I have created a docker image of our node application and pushed it to AWS ECR registry. While using that image to run a container on ECS as well as in EC2 it is taking a long time start running. The response I'm getting after waiting for nearly 5 minutes is this:

```
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

up to date in 277.487s
```

After that also, it took a lot of time to start.

When I try to run on a new EC2 t2.micro instance, it shows `Segmentation Fault`. But it ran without any issue on my local machine.

Is this an issue with small instane type (t2.micro) ?

Comment: how much memory is required to ur container on the local machine? run without task definition or service and run in the interactive mood it seems like ur also installing npm on bootup so will you will have a better picture before any changes.

Comment: I ran it in a t2.medium instance and it takes less that 500MB memory. And it also ran faster than the other instance (t2.micro).

Comment: So in T2.micro, you have only 1GB memory.  Memory might be the reason. https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Comment: And how much memory you have set in task definiation in case of t2 micro?

Comment: You aren’t running `npm install` as part of the container startup, are you?  Can you add your `Dockerfile` to the question?